# how to get message when i click on submit?

Tags: php

i'm new to php, i want when i click on submit button to see page `action.php` message.

**index.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="action.php">

             <div class="form-group">
              <label>nom</label>
              <input type="text" name="nom" class="form-control">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <label>description</label>
              <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <label>body</label>
              <textarea type="text" name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <input  class="btn btn-warning form-control" name="submit" value="submit">
             </div>

            </form>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    echo "btn submit click";
}

?>
```

Comment: The input needs `type="submit"`.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana you should read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Comment: Yikes, understood now, deleted it. Thank you so so so much @JayBlanchard. I realise that now. Maybe you delete/edit that so that, that topic is not going to interfere this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input needs `type="submit"`.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning form-control" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

your input should be

```
<input class="btn btn-warning form-control" type="submit">
```

instead of

```
<input  class="btn btn-warning form-control" name="submit" value="submit">
```